# Does Sequelize have a way to find or select a subset of fields?

Tags: node.js, django, sequelize.js

Say I have the following Django code using [`.only()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#only):

```
Person.objects.only("name")
```

Is there a similar way in [Sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) to generate SQL (preferably not using [Raw Queries](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html)) which returns only a subset of all the fields stored in my DB?

Answer (score 2):

From sequelize [documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#specifying-attributes-for-select-queries)

To select only some attributes, you can use the attributes option:

```
Model.findAll({
  attributes: ['foo', 'bar']
});
```